# when is after_touch callback in rails called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

How does `after_touch` callback work in Rails? Is it called whenever an object is updated or only when a new object is created?

Comment: This seems like more of a google question than a StackOverflow question - it's a very simple question about the API.

Comment: eg googling "after_touch callback rails" brings me here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Even 8 years later, it's still not 100% clear in the API docs, but this is ONLY called when a model is EXPLICITLY touched, and not just when the timestamps are updated for some other reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It'll be called only if the object is touched:

```
object.touch # after_touch will be called
```

[Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e36db4406beea32772b1db1e9a16cc1e8aea14c/guides/source/active_record_callbacks.md#after_touch) you could find more info.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that in Rails 7, `touch` [triggers callbacks.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#running-callbacks)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

both the time when new object is created or an object is updated after_touch callback works.